# I want the og tag to be the same as the title tag in WordPress, what should I do?

Tags: wordpress, seo

I want the meta og:title tag to be the same as the title tag in WordPress, what should I do?
i have yoast plugin but og:title tag is same with page or post name
Is there a code for this?
There doesn't seem to be a plugin for this